# Java Virtual Machine Launcher - could not find the main class

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I am working on my GUI application in Eclipse IDE. When I am trying to run it, the following error message is thrown:

> Java Virtual Machine Launcher - Could not find the main
>   class:org.cnstar.wiki.app.GreatPlaces.Program will exit.

---

Update: here is how my main method looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        NativeInterface.open(); 

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // loading the Splash Panel
                    SplashPanel panel = new SplashPanel();
                    SplashManager manager = new SplashManager(panel);
                    panel.setMessage("Initializing...");
                    manager.repaint();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        panel.setProgress(i);
                        manager.repaint();
                    try {
                      Thread.sleep(100);
                        } 
                    catch (Exception e) {
                       }
                    }
                    manager.closeSplash();

                    start_application();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        NativeInterface.runEventPump();
    }
```

And the methods connected to main method:

```
private static void start_application() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
                    GreatPlaces window = new GreatPlaces(true, true);
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

public GreatPlaces(final boolean fullscreen, boolean showSplashScreen) {
        LocaleHandler.setLocale(); // will set the application language based to the local language of the machine

        initialize(fullscreen, showSplashScreen);

        setViewLayout();

        installAction();
    }
```

---

PROBLEM FOUND:
I have just reinstalled my JRE, make clean to my project and it suddenly started to work! 
Thanks all for help!

Comment: Post the code of your main class, which is supposed to contains `public static void main( String[] args )`

Comment: the class itself contains more than 500 lines, so I will rather post here the main method:

Comment: reinstalling to fix a problem is like taking the engine out of your car and just putting it back in to fix a problem, you still have no idea what the root cause was, not very productive or helpful in the long run

Answer (score 0):

Check that you .project file in eclipse work space has the following

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Or Check the ouput folder for your compiled java class in eclipse is correct

Java Build Path --> Source -->Default Output folder

Comment: just chcked and it is there.

Comment: Is Build Automatically in eclipse turned on ?

Comment: Check the ouput folder for you compiled java class in eclipse is correct 

Java Build Path --> Source -->Default Output folder

Comment: Yeah, Build Automatically is turned on and the output folder is set properly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've defined the main method in an inner class. See this question posted earlier: [Main method in a static inner class.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125995/main-method-in-a-static-inner-class)

That is, if you want to have it in an inner class, then you'll need to define the main class as such:

```
org.cnstar.wiki.app.GreatPlaces$Program
```

Comment: No, this is not the case, main method is a method of the class GreatPlaces.

Comment: Ok. Then, are you using the same Java version for compiling and running?