# Error: main method not found in class XXX, please define the main method

Tags: java

## Issue

I've problem on basic level with mine code.
Its get compiled into bytecode properly with Javac but after that i cant invoke it with java command

I've tried to set main method elsewhere but code for me doesnt seem to be enough transparent. Im learning from "Head First Java" and i attended to short Java course.
I think that i understand concept but its hard for me to be one step ahead the compiler

## Code

```
class dog {
int size; 
String breed;
String name;
static void bark() {
System.out.println("ruff ruff");
}
static  class dogtest{


public static void main(String[] args) {
dog d = new dog();
d.size = 12;
d.bark();

}
}
}
```

Error I've got:

```
Error: Main method not found in class dog, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Comment: Your `main` method is inside `dogtest`, not `dog` .

Comment: Also if you really intend to have a main static inner class, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125995/main-method-in-a-static-inner-class

Comment: java class Names should start with Upper Case Letter. Dog not dog, DogTest not dogtest. see here : https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dog{
int size; 
String breed;
String name;
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("ruff ruff");
        }
private static class DogTest{
                System.out.println("Static inner class");

    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.size = 12;
        d.bark();

        }
}
```