# Compiler looking for main method in wrong class

Tags: java

My program has no errors found when I finished typing it up and no warnings.  However, when I run it from the command line with "java Junk.java" it says this:

can't find main(String[]) method in class: Snack

I am confused why it is looking in the Snack class for the main method.  I am new to java but this makes no sense to me, as I have declared the main method in the class with the same name as the java file.  The file is titled Junk.java and is a work in progress.

```
class Snack {
int calories;
int carbs;
int weightInOunces;


double conversion() {
    return carbs/weightInOunces;
    }        
}
class Junk{    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snack Twinkie=new Snack();
        Snack DingDong=new Snack();

        Twinkie.weightInOunces=4;
        Twinkie.carbs=45;
        Twinkie.calories=150;
    
        System.out.println("The Twinkie weighs "+Twinkie.weightInOunces+" ounces");
        System.out.println("The Twinkie has "+Twinkie.carbs+" carbs.");
        System.out.println("The Twinkie has "+Twinkie.calories+" calories.");
        System.out.println("The Twinkie is "+Twinkie.conversion()+"carbs per ounce");
    
    
    }
    
double conversion() {
    return carbs/weightInOunces;
    }        
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the Snack class?

Comment: Just added the snack class.  Sorry about the omission.

Comment: @JonathanVT you could remove the inner class snack that you have declared inside the Junk class. It looks redundant.

Comment: @JonathanVT Which java version are you using?

Comment: @JonathanVT I hope you are running the compilation command [javac Junk.java] before trying the execution command[java Junk]. Your execution command looks faulty. Remove the .java extension while executing.

Comment: @TheViper It is possible with java 11, see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Comment: @Progman thanks for the info, never used Java 11 actually :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java file contains 2 classes, i.e. `Junk` and `Snack`

Generally when this is the case, the class that contains the

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

method, is usually declared as `public`. You could declare the `Junk` class as `public`
and check the output.

Otherwise it looks for the main method in the first class that it sees which is(in this case): `Snack`
This link might also be helpful for you:
[Main method in a static inner class.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125995/main-method-in-a-static-inner-class)

Comment: I don't think so, it is package by default I think. @DaveCat

Comment: I think you're actually correct. Access modifiers are public, private, protected, default. The default modifier is accessible only within package. It cannot be accessed from outside the package.